# What's could be wrong with this code posting a object in the database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a post request to a table, using Express, Sequelize, MySQL and Postman to test the request. I'm getting an error with Sequelize not recognizing a field.

The query is not inserting the field `IdProduto`, I don't know why, I've checked the spelling a million times, checked all the files related and also the database table.

Executing (default):

```
SELECT `idPedidos`, `idCliente_fk`, `idRestaurante_fk`, `valorCompra`, `horarioChegada`, `statusPedido`, `IdProduto`
FROM `Pedidos`
AS `Pedidos`;
```

Executing (default):

```
INSERT INTO `Pedidos` (`idPedidos`,`valorCompra`,`horarioChegada`,`statusPedido`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`idCliente_fk`,`idRestaurante_fk`)
VALUES (DEFAULT,40,30,'Feito','2019-05-29 23:03:41','2019-05-29 23:03:41',14,16);`
```

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Field 'IdProduto' doesn't
>   have a default value

Here is my code that make the post.

```
exports.post = (req, res, next) => {
    models.Pedidos.create({
        IdProduto: req.body.IdProduto,
        idCliente_fk: req.body.idCliente_fk,
        idRestaurante_fk: req.body.idRestaurante_fk,
        valorCompra: req.body.valorCompra,
        horarioChegada: req.body.horarioChegada,
        statusPedido: req.body.statusPedido
    }).then((result) => res.json(result))
};
```

Here is the json I'm using in postman.

```
{
    "idRestaurante_fk":16,
    "valorCompra":40,
    "horarioChegada":30,
    "statusPedido":"Feito",
    "idCliente_fk":14,
    "IdProduto":2
}
```

Also I've checked the names in the table, and it's all right. I was thinking about setting the default value in the database myself, but it will not work, because in the console the INSERT query executed shows that the `IdProduto` is not getting inserted. Not sure what can be wrong here.

Comment: How did you created the column `IdProduto` in the table `Pedidos`? As an autoincrement key? Plain value?

Comment: I wrote a migration to create it in the table `Pedidos`, the value is integer not null. `alter table Pedidos add column IdProduto int not null, add foreign key (IdProduto) references Produtos(IdProduto)`.

Comment: To me it looks like your problem is the fact that you are not including `IdProduto` in your `INSERT` statement, yet the column itself is set to `NOT NULL`. Either you need to provide a value for the `IdProduto` as part of your `INSERT` statement, or you need to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint from the `IdProduto` table (removing the constraint is probably not what you want since it looks like you have a foreign key relation setup).

Comment: Yea that's the problem, but the query is auto generated, I'm sending it in the json. I don't know why it's not going in the insert query.